# Edit virtual host file using php

Tags: php, apache

I have a php application and somethings related to the application need changes to vhost.conf file.

Presently i'm making the changes manually. But i would like to automate it using a php script.

Is this advisable? I want to know the security complications involved.

Comment: Please clarify: a standalone PHP script (to be run via the CLI interpreter), or PHP running in a webserver context?

Comment: @mr.spuratic What would be the difference?

Answer (score 3):

Among the many reasons why I would *not even think* about doing what you're contemplating, these would be my Top-3:

1. **Security:**
   I would never put any file that modifies a system's configuration file in a publicly accessible area. The reason is simple: the publicly accessible area is most vulnerable. If the file gets modded by someone (friend or foe), the modification could cause havoc to both your file system, as well as your server and/or system configuration.
2. **Integrity:**
   PHP can (and probably will) mess up file locking. As a result, [race-conditions](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Race_Conditions) might destroy your `vhosts.conf` file and break your server configuration.
3. **Recovery:**
   Changes to `vhost.conf` need a server restart for the changes to be acknowledged by the server. You will need to think how you're going to handle that restart via PHP... and what happens when something goes wrong.  *If* your server crashes and takes down the PHP engine while it's at it (remember [Murphy's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)), how are you going to automatically recover from that? PHP won't be of any help in that case.